# Pipe trigger for click event in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a custom pipe for filter a dataset by a given term named searchterm. I have created this as markup.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list | searchterm: value">
        Say {{item.title}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

"value" is coming from another component's input element. When every time I change the input text, it instantly activate the pipe. I need to activate the pipe only when clicking on a button in the other component.

I have created this so far:

```
<button (click)="showResult(searchterm)">Search</button>
```

and in the component:

```
showResult(strCat:booblean){
  this.strCat = true;
}
```

and now I stuck with going further.... how I can manage this?

Comment: [Filtering pipes are discouraged](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Comment: what is the reason?

Comment: Well the links explains it pretty well. Mostly performance and aggressive minification.

Comment: what kind of communication your components have sibling sibling, parent to child, child to parent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a pipe if you don't want it to be applied instantly.

Instead, filter the list in a function that is executed on a button click.

If you need to communicate between the two components use a suitable inter component communication strategy as laid down here:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

My fave: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Or use ngrx